# Movie producer decides to make a movie about a trip to Mars using a Mars expedition ship that was built and never used

Tags: story-identification, novel, mars

I'm trying to remember the author and title of an SF novel about a trip to Mars.

In this world, a Mars expedition had been planned and the expedition ship built, but the project was cancelled for lack of funding.

Then some Hollywood mogul decides to make a blockbuster movie about a trip to Mars, using the actual ship to travel to Mars.

Notable aspects - films these days are made entirely in computers. The only reason they use cameras is to do motion capture of the actors, and that only because the union rules require it. Every film must include some quantity of footage shot of actual union actors.

Said actors don't act, they don't even speak; the film crews just film them walking around in a circle for the requisite number of hours. But the actors need to be members of the Screen Actors Guild - membership in which is now hereditary.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: This has "The Technicolor Time Machine" by Harrison vibes.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Is this ***[Voyage to the Red Planet](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/417990)*** (1990) by Terry Bisson...?

> An extraordinary science fiction tour de force about the first trip to the planet Mars, filled with action, humor, and pathos. One of the finest, most carefully written science fiction extrapolations in years.
>
> [image: Front cover of "Voyage to the Red Planet" (1990) by Terry Bisson.]

From a [review](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/sfreviews/RR00139.html):

> It is sometime in the not-too-distant future. The U.S. government has long since sold off its space program (along with the Navy, the Park Service, the Smithsonian and about everything else). The lawyers and megacorporations are kings. The Soviet Union is gone. And the only entity left with both the money and the desire to finish an abandoned Mars project is --- Hollywood.
>
> **Hollywood, in the person of a B-movie producer named Markson trying for the coup of his career. So he assembles a crew; an ex-cosmonaut, an ex-astronaut, a Hollywood doctor, a dwarf production genius and two Movie Stars. No mistake about the capitals; Cary Fonda-Fox IV and Beverly Glen are gene-engineered thoroughbreds born to a hereditary aristocracy. They board a mothballed Mars ship completed years before one step ahead of a pack of lawyers and head for the Red Planet to make the ultimate docu-drama.**

I checked the [Google Books preview](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Voyage_to_the_Red_Planet/dnJZL2SLd5wC?hl=en&kptab=editions&gbpv=0), and there is a mention of the actors walking around in circles during on location filming.

> Now that the actual location filming had begun, his days of playing Fourth Officer were over. He was stuck "on set" with Glamour and Greetings, walking circles in the sand.

There's also a mention of the Academy having hereditary members.

> was a tribute the genetic engineering the Academy made available to its hereditary members.